# How to specifiy rootfolder with openFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

With folderBrowseDialog you can show the top level of the folder which will be shown initially. However that feature is not there on openFileDialog.

I want to let the user open files from a specific folder only. How do I specify the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [`openFileDialog.InitialDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: How can i restrict the user from accessing other folders? can i lock them?

Comment: you should be an administarator of your  system  to this

Answer (score 1):

Set [InitialDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = @"D:\SomeFolder";
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks! But incase the files are in a different folder. Need to point to the application's folder no matter where it is

Comment: I have a folder named object_files in my project folder and i need the file opened to be copied there. So in order to mention the destination folder.  rather than typing the long path i want to find a way to specify the path. And the path may change if the project folder is moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Gawjus, answering your question "How can I restrict the user from accessing other folders? can I lock them?", you can use *Environment Special Folder* as per code below, but as far I know you cannot define a custom folder, there are some options available. Another way it's to create an UserControl that list only files from a specific folder. Doing that you can have more control how it will behave.

> ofd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments;